# Setter method questions

Tags: ios, setter

In xcode I've noticed there is a method created automatically when a property is used.

For example, if I enter `@property(nonatomic)BOOL selected;` in an `@interface` a method gets created in the background which can be used in the `@implementation` looking like this:

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {}
```

Now I don't really know what this is called but I assume it's called setter method, now I figured I could use this for some stuff when setting the `selected boolean` but when I call it and it's empty; nothing happens, not even `selected` gets assigned a value, and when I enter:

```
self.selected = selected;
```

It runs into an endless loop and the app crashes, is there an easy way to sop that infinite loop or should I not use these kind of methods?

**FIXED**

I synthesized the `self.selected` and now it does not loop.

```
@synthesize selected;

-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected_ {
    selected = selected_;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the backing iVar for the `selected` property in the setter

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
  if (_selected != selected) {
     _selected = selected;
  }
}
```

Assigning `self.selected = selected` will call the setter, and calling this inside the setting will result in an endless loop!

Comment: I synthesized the self.selected and now it works, even without the if statement :)

Comment: @Arbitur you shouldn't need to synthesize the property as the property declaration does that.
The `if` statement is so it doesn't needless get set if the value has not changed.

Comment: well, I've already tried with the if statement and it didnt work, oddly. But the synthesizing did the trick ;) And your _selected made me think of it. I dont usually synthesize x)